# While an existing transition or presentation is occurring; the navigation stack will not be updated

Tags: ios, swift

I have encountered this warning:

> pushViewController:animated: called on  while an existing transition or presentation is
>   occurring; the navigation stack will not be updated.

While trying to call `navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(false)` from `UIAlertController` completion block.

Comment: not getting your question properly!

Comment: make your question clearly?

Comment: i got this warning: pushViewController:animated: called on <UINavigationController 0x7ff2e28b0000> while an existing transition or presentation is occurring; the navigation stack will not be updated.

Comment: I have calling  navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(false) in alert controller action's completion handler

Comment: Hello @SidduHalake any update regarding above issue or any idea to resolve.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This warning indicates that you are trying use `UINavigationController` wrongly:

> pushViewController:animated: called on  while an existing transition or presentation is occurring; the navigation stack will not be updated

You mentioned in the comments that you are trying to `pop` the
`ViewController` using

```
navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(false)
```

inside completion block of `UIAlertController`. Therefore, you are trying to unwind from the wrong view, **`UIAlertController` is not part of the `UINavigationController` stack**.

Try and close the `UIAlertController` first, then pop the current `ViewController`. In other words, remove the `pop` from the `completion` block and put it inside the `OK` block. or use `unwind` segue before the alert.

Another possibility, is that you have an unused or identical duplicate in `storyboard`. Hence, if the `unwinding` operation is triggered by `storyboard` button, select this button and check the `connectivity inspector` and removed unwanted connections.

For example: the red x marked was unnecessary in my case.
[image: Example]

Comment: Perfect. It's easy to forget alerts are view controllers.

Answer (score 27):

I solved this using **DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter** call popviewcontroller after the UIAlertController's Transition complete

1) Show Alert

2) Call pop viewcontroller after delay

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
}
```

This is not best way, but it works!

Comment: This works fine...

Answer (score 4):

Add the code of navigate controller on the ok action button handler. When Tap on ok button navigate the view controller

```
let okActionBtn = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: {
      self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
})
let cancelActionBtn = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Message", preferredStyle: .alert)
alert.addAction(okActionBtn)
alert.addAction(cancelActionBtn)
self.present(alert, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 2):

i am using  **dispatch_async**  and **its working**. i tried to navigate back but didn't worked **because navigation stack will not be updated.**

```
let destVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController
    self.presentViewController(destVC, animated: true, completion: {() -> Void in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {() -> Void in
            self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)!
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

My Solution would be to call dismissViewControllerAnimated: first and then pop the viewcontroller from navigation stack this works for me :-

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:false completion:nil];
[myNavigationControllerInstance popToRootViewControllerAnimated:true]; // myNavigationControllerInstance = Your Navigation Controller Instance
```

Answer (score 1):

Anyone needs go back to **PreviousVC** Use this code. **Swift5**

```
    dismiss(animated: true) {
        // If you need call someFunction()
        self.someFunction()
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: To add to this: don't forget `self` in most cases, so `self.dismiss(animated: true) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

In my case I wrote like following.

```
secondVC.dismiss(animated : true)
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(thirdVC, animated: true)
```

Then I replace that to this and now it's working.

```
secondVC.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(thirdVC, animated: true)
})
```